# How do I rotate a AVAsset to portrait mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video, avasset

I import a video from the iPhone library and I apply some effects to that video. The problem is that the video has a wrong orientation (landscape). How can I rotate the video to portrait mode?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a transform on the AVPlayerLayer?

```
self.videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.videoPlayer];
self.videoLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0f, 0, 0, 1);
```